# Android - How to get key name from JSON in addition to the value

Tags: android, json, key, key-value

I have an Android project where I'm using some data from stored JSON. I'm using it in several places to get the values, but now, I would also need to get the name of the key instead of value. Is it possible somehow? I'm using 'org.json' library to parse the JSON.

My JSON:

```
{
  "cookbook": {
    "products": {
      "factory1": {
        "product": "product1",
        "rate": 2,
      },
      "factory2": {
        "product": "product2",
        "rate": 14,
        "requires": {
          "money": 20,
          "product3": 3,
          "product4": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As I said, I have not a problem with retrieving the values, but now I have a name of a product in a variable, let's say 'product2' and I need to determine, which factory is producing this product. So I need to get return 'factory2'.

I have tried:

```
    mainCookbookJson = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset(activity, "cookbook.json"));
    JSONObject cookbookJson = mainCookbookJson.getJSONObject("cookbook");
    JSONObject productsJson = cookbookJson.getJSONObject("products");

    for(Iterator<String> iter = productsJson.keys(); iter.hasNext();) {
        String key = iter.next();
        if (productsJson.getJSONObject(key).getString("product").equals(product)) {
            return productsJson.getString(key);
          //return productsJson.getJSONObject(key).toString(); // Also tried
        }
    }
```

but this is returning the whole object formatted as a String.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You probably want to return `key` since that has the values `factory1`, `factory2` etc

Comment: @Apoorv Yes, exactly. That's what I need and what is stated in the question, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Oh, I see, you meant a variable name 'key'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just returning the `key`.

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = productsJson.keys(); iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
    if (productsJson.getJSONObject(key).getString("product").equals(product)) {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: What a straightforward solution. Thanks a lot, it works.